# Javascript alert not working possibly due to array syntax

Tags: javascript, alert

this is my first time trying to incorporate an array into my javascript code. I am using this with a form that contains a text input in which only the colors Blue, Yellow, Gray, Orange or Pink can be submitted, otherwise there should be an alert. Clearly I have made some error as my values are not being picked up...anything can be entered into the input #color and the form can still be submitted, no alert ever populates regardless of what I enter.
Code is below.
Thank you.

```
    }   
  // Verifies Colors 
  var colors = ["Blue", "Yellow", "Gray", "Orange", "Pink"];
      if ($('#color').val() != colors) {
          alert("These are not the right colors!");
          return false;       
        }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole function? If it's not too large of course. There are brackets here that don't have any meaning.

Comment: You're comparing a single element's value to an entire Array of "possible" colors. You need iterate through the colors and see if any of them are being used. If so, return a true and all is well, else return a false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if(colors.indexOf($("#color").val()) == -1 ){
    alert("These are not the right colors!");
    return false;
}
```

[edit]
This is an assumption, I think #colors is a input type="text", or a select, in either case, I would suggest to pay attention to the capitalization of words, considering that the input might be all lowercase or all uppercase or a MiX oF BoTh.

Comment: Thank you very much Rafael! This works perfectly and I appreciate your point about variations on input. I will definitely have to address that somehow. Regards, Jenny (zipotontic)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jquery.

```
var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'whatever'];
if ($.inArray($("#color").val(), colors) < 0) {
    alert("These are not the right colors!");
    return false;
}
```

To Rafael's, and Kyle's, point though jquery will use indexOf if it can, from the jquery source

```
inArray: function( elem, arr, i ) {
    var len;

    if ( arr ) {
        if ( core_indexOf ) {
            return core_indexOf.call( arr, elem, i );
        }

        len = arr.length;
        i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i : 0;

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            // Skip accessing in sparse arrays
            if ( i in arr && arr[ i ] === elem ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Where core_indexOf is an alias for array.indexOf

```
core_indexOf = core_deletedIds.indexOf
```

Comment: Had to edit it.  Less than zero is false, not greater than -1 (What I had originally).  Check out jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: might be worth noting that using `indexOf` is quicker than using `$.inArray` if the browser supports it. See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883663/should-i-use-jquery-inarray

Comment: Any JS native function is probably faster than <library name here>.  This was just the fastest thing I could come up with and I was uncertain if indexOf worked like that.  The only example I found was w3c and for string manipulation.

Comment: I would like to add that indexOf is not supported in IE8. Casually, today I had a problem with that at work.