# How to addClass to a cell or td if value from an array of innerHTML present in it?

Tags: jquery

Recently started learning JQuery and  haven't had success on this fo some time now. I am trying to add an array of innerHTML (values from DB) to existing array (something like 'Push') and also give the td's of those array values a class.

My code is:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active-select-color');
    if($('td').hasClass('active-select-color'))
        $('#mark-now').show();
    else
        $('#mark-now').hide();
});

/* Here I need to add class to "td" containing values from 'PreDates' array */
/* And then push values to array 'selected' */
var PreDates = ["1","2"];
PreDates.adClass('active-select-color');

var selected = [];
var tbl = document.getElementById("calender-table");
if (tbl != null) {
for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
        var item = getval(this);
        if($(this).hasClass('active-select-color')){ 
        selected.push(item);
    } else {
        var index = selected.indexOf(item);
        selected.splice(index, 1);
        }
document.getElementById("dates").value = selected;
        }
    }
}
function getval(cel) {
  return cel.innerHTML;
}
```

Html table is:

```
<table border="1" id="calender-table">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>

<input id="dates" type="text" value="" />
<div id="mark-now">Mark As Booked<div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a "d" in the call to `addClass`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the d is not the problem, it's an array, addClass on an array, looks familiar?  :-)

Comment: @sarepta Not familiar, but afaik, only HTML elements have an `addClass` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run through all the `td`s and compare values with array. If found in array then `addClass` to that td

```
    /* Here I need to add class to "td" containing values from 'PreDates' array */
    /* And then push values to array 'selected' */
    var PreDates = ["1","2"];
    //PreDates.addClass('active-select-color');
    var selected = [];
   $("#calender-table td").each(function() {
     if (isInArray($(this).html(), PreDates)) {
       $(this).addClass('active-select-color');
       selected.push($(this).html());
     }
     document.getElementById("dates").value = selected;
    });

    function isInArray(value, array) {
      return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @KumarM.. By the way I also find a solution (Please check my solution).. Do you think anyone of this would be faster than another? I would be glad to accept your answer but just a thought :-)

Comment: oh I see. both are almost similar, but native javascript functions are faster and better to use when possible. javascript `array.indexOf` is faster than jquery `inArray'  as per this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883663/should-i-use-jquery-inarray :)

Comment: And now my real problem is that `PreDates` array is an php array.. which I can echo in Jquery like `<?= json_encode($PreDates); ?>`.. but its not working... This echos in source as `"1,2,3,4"` while I need it as `["1","2","3","4"]`

Comment: try using `function isInArray(value, array) {
  return array.indexOf(Number(value)) > -1;
}`   here I'm type casting value to integer.

Answer (score 0):

I completely removed-

```
var PreDates = ["1","2"];
PreDates.adClass('active-select-color');
var selected = [];
```

Rplaced with:

```
var selected = ["1","2"];
$("td").each(function() {
  if(jQuery.inArray($(this).html(), selected) !== -1) {
  $(this).addClass("active-select-color");
  }
});
```